# How to deal with nested protocols and generics for Python stubs

Tags: python, generics, protocols, mypy, typing

I'm trying to define a `Protocol` for a `Stream` object. `Stream` should be generic over two parameters: inputs and outputs. `Stream` defines methods that return a new stream with the new inputs being the outputs from the original stream and the output something else. For example, the `map` and `sliding_window` operations can be defined as follows:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import (
    Callable,
    Protocol,
    TypeVar,
    Tuple,
)

U = TypeVar("U", contravariant=True)
V = TypeVar("V")
T = TypeVar("T")


class StreamInterface(Protocol[U, V]):
    def map(
        self: StreamInterface[U, V],
        func: Callable[[V], T],
    ) -> StreamInterface[V, T]:
        ...

     def sliding_window(
        self: StreamInterface[U, V],
        n: int,
     ) -> StreamInterface[V, Tuple[V, ...]]:
        ...
```

I now want to define a `flatten` operation which should behave as follows:

```
K = TypeVar("K")
IterableK = Iterable[K]
M = TypeVar("M", bound=IterableK)

...
     def flatten(
        self: StreamInterface[U, M],
     ) -> StreamInterface[M, K]:
        ...
```

Effectively this operation will only work if `V` is an iterable, which I try to enforce with the `M` typehint.

However, mypy seems to no longer be able to follow the types:

```
def func1(input: int) -> float:
    return input + 1.2

source: StreamInterface[int, int] = Stream()
slider = source.map(func1).sliding_window(3)
flattened = slider.flatten()  # mypy complains that flattened needs a type hint
flattened.map(func2).sink(print)
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that `K` and `M` are defined separately from `U` and `V`, but if I use `V` it doesn't work because `self: StreamInterface[U, Iterable[V]]` is not properly dealt with.

I'm wondering what the best way would be to deal with typing the `flatten` method.

Comment: As long as there is no support for higher-kinded types in python (HKT), you're out of luck, the best would be `def flatten(self: StreamInterface[U, Iterable[K]]) -> StreamInterface[Iterable[K], K]` if you absolutely have to enforce iterable. This obviously upcasts first argument too much, you forget everything about it except for it being an `Iterable[K]`. And please make this an MRE: I had to edit too much, and it's still not complete enough. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.8.0&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=cfa55c3c0d8c619fd3b6ddbd4387c275

Comment: Also check out https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/hkt.html for a library that provides a `mypy` plugin with some HKT support.

Comment: These comments are very helpful, thank you! Sorry that my example was not runnable, I will add one.